# for bundle tools, package.json `exports` and `module`, which has higher priority?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

most of modern bundle tools support both top-level `module` and `exports`
so I wonder which one has more priority?

```json
{

  "module": './index-es.js',
  exports:{
     "." :{
       import: "./index-es.js" 
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean `"type": "module"`? Not sure what you're referring to. Can you [edit] your question to include a sample package.json?

Comment: @Bergi  updated. the top-level `module` field

Comment: I can't see either of these properties in [the package.json documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json). Where are they defined?

Comment: @Quentin https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html?spm=ata.21736010.0.0.3d314bfcjrqivI#packages_package_entry_points

Comment: `module` is a proposal but not adopted by node, most of bundle tools support this feature for better tree shaking